# High order derivatives of chebyshev polynomials needed

Tags: orthogonal, collocation

I need to evaluate high order (up to 4) derivatives of Chebyshev polynomials at points of the so called Chebyshev grid,

x(j)=cos(πj/N),  j=0,...,N

Anyone know how to do that? I tried iterative methods but they are too clumsy.
I remember seeing something like that in an old paper but now it's nowhere to be found.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on a different StackExachange, such as [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com)?. This doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.

Comment: You are right, I'll post it there

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (though this might be the iterative method you reject) is to use the recurrence:

```
T[n+1]'/(n+1) - T[n-1]'/(n-1) = 2T[n]   n>=2
```

This requires one to be able to compute the derivatives of the first 3 polynomials by hand, but since

```
T[0](x) = 1
T[1](x) = x
T[2](x) = 2*x*x-1
```

this is straightforward.

The coefficients in the recurrence are independent of x, so that if T[j,k] is the k'th derivative of the j'th Chebyshev poly, we can easily differentiate it, getting

```
T[n+1, k]/(n+1) - T[n-1,k]/(n-1) = 2T[n,k-1]    n>=2
```

So the code could be:

```
compute the T[n,0] (ie the polynomials) at the point, for n=0..deg
initialise T[j,d] for j=0,1,2 and the required degrees
for j=1..deg
   use the recurrence to compute the remaining polynomials
```